# Expanding a Function into a Series and Plotting it

Tags: plotting, series-expansion

I'm trying to expand the function: f(x)=cos(2x)sin(x/2) into two series (let x0=0) of small x, with the first series being 5 terms and the second series being 15 terms. Then plot the function and the two series on a graph.

Anyone know how to do this? I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out, but am not advanced enough at Mathematica to know how to even approach it.

Comment: `f = Series[Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 5}] // Normal;
g = Series[Sin[x/2], {x, 0, 15}] // Normal;
h = Cos[2 x] Sin[x/2];
Plot[{f, g, h}, {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: @ cvgmt There is a bug in your first function as you readily see from the plot. It should read: f = Series[Cos[2 x] Sin[x/2], {x, 0, 5}] // Normal;